# Add new column of rows frequency in R

Tags: r

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
   var1 var2
1    a    d
2    b    e
3    b    e
4    c    f
5    c    f
6    c    f
```

How could count rows frequency by adding a new column `frequency`? Thanks.

```
   var1 var2  frequency
1    a    d      1
2    b    e      2
3    b    e      2
4    c    f      3
5    c    f      3
6    c    f      3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ave` with `length` to *count the rows frequency*.

```
x$frequency <- ave(seq_len(nrow(x)), x, FUN=length)
x
#  var1 var2 frequency
#1    a    d         1
#2    b    e         2
#3    b    e         2
#4    c    f         3
#5    c    f         3
#6    c    f         3
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="   var1 var2
1    a    d
2    b    e
3    b    e
4    c    f
5    c    f
6    c    f")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `match` (based on @GKi's data):
First, make a frequency table `y` of the rows by collapsing them into strings:

```
y <- as.data.frame(table(apply(x, 1, paste0, collapse = " ")))
```

Then, transfer the frequencies to `x` by `match`ing the corresponding rows in `x`and `y`:

```
x$freq <-  y$Freq[match(apply(x[,1:2], 1, paste0, collapse = " "), y$Var1)]
```

Result:

```
x
  var1 var2 freq
1    a    d    1
2    b    e    2
3    b    e    2
4    c    f    3
5    c    f    3
6    c    f    3
```